# Select over serval tables

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

**Table a:**

```
userid | text

     9 | Lorem ipsum do...
```

**Table b:**

```
id | status

 9 | 1
```

**Question:**

I want to select * from `table a` where `table b` under connection from uid -> where the id `status=1` is. I don't know if it's possible.
I searched about it, but I've found nothing.

My Query:

```
SELECT * FROM tablea a WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM tableb b WHERE b.status='1' AND b.id = a.userid)
```

Comment: Please search for JOIN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**inner join**

```
select * 
from a inner join b on a.userid = b.id 
where b.status = 1;
```

**left join**

```
select * 
from a left join b on a.userid = b.id 
where b.status = 1;
```

or

**right join**

```
select * 
from a right join b on a.userid = b.id 
where b.status = 1;
```

see demo here: [**SqlFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5df65c/1)

Check the sqlfiddle to see the difference, it is more if you expect that id exists in table-a or not, where it exists in table-b with status=1.

If you skip the b.status then you might need to go for the inner join query.

Please study the different query to learn about joins, go to the sqlfiddle and remove the b.status condition to see the results.

Take a look at join image below and learn the difference with easy illustration...
[image]

Comment: Based on the question, he probably wants a join rather than a left join.